# Geom_function: Can't recycle `x` (size 101) to match `y` (size 71)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate a model I have successfully plotted in base plot() with ggplot(). It plotted once with the code below, but now it is giving the following error:

Caused by error in `data_frame()`:

! Can't recycle `x` (size 101) to match `y` (size 71).

The error shows up twice, my guess is because for each geom_function() in the code. Any ideas what this means or how to fix the issue?

```
#Functions used in ggplot
vbf.func.fem <-function(age, A, Ti, k) {
  A * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * k * (age_vec - Ti))))^3

}


vbf.func.male <-function(age, A, Ti, k, Adiff, Tidiff, kdiff) {
  (A + Adiff) * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * (k + kdiff) * (age_vec - (Ti + Tidiff)))))^3
  
}

# manually save the parameter estimates to objects
A.est <- 18.814742
Ti.est <- 7.259709
k.est <- 0.031346 
age_vec <- seq(0, 70)
a.est.diff <- -0.920932
ti.est.diff <- 0.230792 
k.est.diff <- 0.002064

#plotting 
ggplot() +
  xlim(0,75) +
  ylim(0, 25) +
  geom_function(fun = vbf.func.fem, args = list(A = A.est, Ti = Ti.est, k = k.est), color = 'blue') +
  geom_function(fun = vbf.func.male, args = list(A = A.est, Ti = Ti.est, k = k.est, Adiff = a.est.diff, Tidiff = ti.est.diff, kdiff = k.est.diff), color = 'red')


#models to use for base plot
# growth of female
hallux_fem = A.est * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * k.est * (age_vec - Ti.est))))^3

# growth of male
hallux_male = (A.est + a.est.diff) * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * (k.est + k.est.diff) * (age_vec - (Ti.est + ti.est.diff) ))))^3 


graphics.off()
plot(age_vec, hallux_fem, type = "n", cex.lab=0.6, cex.axis=0.75, xlab = "Age (days)", tck=0.01, font.lab=2, ylab = 'Hallux (mm)', las = 1, ylim = c(0,22), xlim = c(0,70), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", bty = "l", cex.lab = 1,axes=T)
lines(age_vec, hallux_fem, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = rgb(0.1,0.1,0.8,1))
lines(age_vec, hallux_male, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = rgb(0,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to modify some part of your code:

```
#Functions used in ggplot
vbf.func.fem <-function(age, A, Ti, k,x) {
  A * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * k * (x - Ti))))^3
  
}


vbf.func.male <-function(age, A, Ti, k, Adiff, Tidiff, kdiff,x) {
  (A + Adiff) * (1 - ((1 / 3) * exp(-(9 / 4) * (k + kdiff) * (x - (Ti + Tidiff)))))^3
  
}

# manually save the parameter estimates to objects
A.est <- 18.814742
Ti.est <- 7.259709
k.est <- 0.031346 
age_vec <- seq(0, 70)
a.est.diff <- -0.920932
ti.est.diff <- 0.230792 
k.est.diff <- 0.002064

#plotting 
ggplot(data.frame(x = age_vec), aes(x = x)) +
  xlim(0,75) +
  ylim(0, 25) +
  geom_function(fun = ~vbf.func.fem(A = A.est, Ti = Ti.est, k = k.est, x = .x), color = 'blue') +
  geom_function(fun = ~vbf.func.male(A = A.est, Ti = Ti.est, k = k.est, Adiff = a.est.diff, Tidiff = ti.est.diff, kdiff = k.est.diff, x = .x), color = 'red')
```

You can see I changed `args` into an anonymous function.

Then the result is :

[image]

I think the reason why your code did not work was because `geom_function` will interpolate the point and the number of x coordinates cannot match with the number of y coordinates.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!